# How to test multiple return values, using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm looking manipulate values from a byte stream. I will receive values in an array, that I'm looking to parse. I'm looking to return a dictionary with the new formatted results. My formatting code is called `index.js`

```
//index.js
function calculateNumbers(numbers)
{   
  results={};
  
  //Summing two values
  sumOfTwo = numbers[0] + numbers[1];  //should be 6
  results.valTwo = sumOfTwo;

  //Summing three values
  sumOfThree = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[3]; //should be 9
  results.valThree = sumOfThree;

  return{
    total:results
  };
}

module.exports = calculateNumbers;
```

For testing I want create a test script to validate my responses (Shown in index.test.js.)

In my function I'm returning `{value:total};` When returning my values in this format my test code returns saying:

```
 Expected: 3
    Received: {"value": {"valThree": NaN, "valTwo": 3}}
```

```
//index.test.js
const calculateNumbers= require("./index");
test("Returns calculations",()=> {
    //expect(0.2 + 0.1).toBeCloseTo(0.3, 5);
    expect(calculateNumbers([1,2,6])).toBe(3,9);

});
```

How can I modify my unit test to parse the new returned value ?

Comment: Hi mm-05, welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure I can understand your question, could you please try to rewrite it to make it more clear?

Comment: Hi Mike, Is there anything in particular  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result of your function is object. You need to assert all object:

```js
expect(calculateNumbers([1,2,6])).toStrictEqual({
  total: {
    valTwo: 3,
    valThree: 9,
  },
});
```